# Access nexus repository in html view, return 500 code and java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, html, web, repository, nexus

When access pypi nexus repository in html view, we get 500 http return code and error message like this:

```
ERROR:(ID ***) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

We have update nexus from version 3.19.1 to 3.47.1. After update, when we browse pypi repository in html view, some pypi modules return such error message, while other modules seem normal.

We have tried delete the module, and download this module from client again, hope to rebuild the index. But we failed, the question still exist.

Finally we delete the pypi repository, and create new blob storage and pypi repository, and the question disapper.
But what's the really reason to cause such problem? Is the bug of new version of nexus?